# I need help finding the limits for integration of a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

Given that:

$x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$

$\int_\alpha^\beta g(t) f'(t)$

$x=8+e^t$ and $y=t-t^2$ bound by the curve given and above the x-axis

I assume I am trying to find values of t?
So far I have this setup:

$\int_\alpha^\beta (t-t^2)e^tdt$

Setting y=0 I get values of $t=0$ and $t=1$. Are these correct?

Setting up the integral I get $\int_0^1 (t-t^2)e^t$
Integration by parts gives:

$u=t-t^2$

$du=1-2tdt$

solving for dt gives $-\frac{1}{2}+du=dt$

$dv=e^t$
$v=e^t$

so we have $\int_0^1 uv-\int vdu \to \int_0^1 e^t(t-t^2)-\int -\frac{1}{2}e^t$

which gives:

$\frac{1}{2}e-\frac{1}{2}$
Can someone offer more hints and point out where I am correct to? I get that setting y=0 is the bound of the x axis but how do I find my other bounds?

Comment: Step 1: Set $y=0$ because you will need those t values

Comment: Bound by the curve and the x-axis, is your important clue here.  At what values of t does the curve cross the x axis?  Is the x coordinate relevant?

Comment: Yes it is important because we are looking where f(x) $\geq$ $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the late replies I had to work over the weekend and I hope I can still get feedback

Comment: Maybe I should use these values of t, where y=0 and plug into x to obtain $x(0)=0-0=0%$ and $x(1)= 1-1^2=0$ But I don't see how this helps me. Or maybe I plug these into y to obtain 1 and e? I don't understand how this helps me.